# cross domain with nuxtjs/axios

Tags: cross-domain, axios, http-proxy, nuxt.js

I want to call a api provided by another domain, follow the official document, this is part of the `nuxt.config.js`：

```
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios'],
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api',
    // prefix: '/api', // it not work
    credentials: true,
  },
  proxy: {
    '/api/douban': {
      target: 'https://api.douban.com',
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
    },
  },
```

and here is the code to call the api:

```
async search({ commit, state }, data) {
  const res = await this.$axios.$get('/douban/book/search', { params: data });
  commit('SET_BOOK_QUERY', res);
  return res;
},
```

but it not work, so i add some log in `http-proxy-middleware` as this：

```
function shouldProxy (context, req) {
    var path = (req.originalUrl || req.url)
    console.log('shouldProxy  path:', context, path);// output：shouldProxy  path: /api/douban /admin/read
    return contextMatcher.match(context, path, req)
  }
```

it seems the config is inited correctly，the problem is only when refreshing page, doing server render and the log output, but request in browser dose not trigger the check.
any help?

---

**update**: i have forgot how to resolve it, but it works now with this config:

```
  this.$axios.$get(
     `/api/proxy/lylares/netmusic/?query=music&id=${id}&limit=2&offset=0`,
     { params: { id, limit, offset } },
  )
```

config：

```
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
    prefix: '/api', // it only work when proxy is enabled
    credentials: true,
  },
  proxy: {
    // '/api/proxy/lylares': {
    //   target: 'https://api.berryapi.net',
    //   changeOrigin: true,
    //   pathRewrite: { '^/api/proxy/lylares': '' },
    // },
    '/api': {
      target: IS_DEV || process.server ? 'http://localhost:8000' : 'https://my.space',
      changeOrigin: true,
    },
  },
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @zerohedge i have updated my question, please check if this can help you